# Problems working with egit and github.

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

OK So I am keeping my projects on GitHub, and I was working on my laptop yesterday and committed and pushed my project up on github using egit on eclipse. When I went to my to update the code on my desktop I am not sure how to bring my code up to the latest version on github. When I try and pull I get the error dialog The current branch is not configured for pull. No value for key branchmaster.merge found in configuration. I am more used to working with SVN and is my first time really updating with git.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a fetch then a merge (which is what pull does internally). In Eclipse, you can right-click a repository in the "Git Repositories" view (if you can't see it, you may want to open it or to use the "Git Repository Exploring" perspective) and choose "Fetch...". This will let you fetch from any configured remote. It may also give you the option to set up "refs to fetch". If it does that, go ahead and click "add all branches spec". After you've fetched, right-click on the repo again and choose "Merge...". Choose the branch under "Remote Tracking" that represents your GitHub remote, then press the merge button.

I can't explain exactly how to go about setting up your repo to let you pull--you might check out http://gitref.org/remotes/#fetch for an easier "getting started" explanation of what's happening when you fetch/pull with git (although it's geared to the command line), and http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_default_behaviour for more information on the behind-the-scenes parts. You may also find it's worth using the command line interface (if you have it available) until you are more familiar with git concepts--you might find it easier.